# openxml with multiple same element name

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @hDoc int

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc output,
'
    <HiringManagers>
      <HiringManagerName>Lauren</HiringManagerName>
      <EmployeeId />
      <Email>Lauren@hello.com</Email>
      <HiringManagerName>Michael </HiringManagerName>
      <EmployeeId />
      <Email>Michael@bye.com</Email>
    </HiringManagers>
'

SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@hdoc, '/HiringManagers')
WITH (Email varchar(30) 'Email',
      HiringManagerName varchar(50) 'HiringManagerName')

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```

Instead of only getting Lauren and her email, how will I get both Lauren and Michael's email and name?

Comment: I removed the openxml tag as this is not related to the Microsoft Office file formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since SQL Server doesn't support the `following-sibling` XPath axes, the following is a workaround. It shreds the XML first in a `HiringManagerName` and `Email` derived table along with the index of occurance in the XML. Then the two are linked on the index.

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '
    <HiringManagers>
      <HiringManagerName>Lauren</HiringManagerName>
      <EmployeeId />
      <Email>Lauren@hello.com</Email>
      <HiringManagerName>Michael </HiringManagerName>
      <EmployeeId />
      <Email>Michael@bye.com</Email>
    </HiringManagers>
';

;WITH ct_mn AS (
    SELECT
        HiringManagerName=n.v.value('(.)','NVARCHAR(256)'),
        rn_index=n.v.value('for $i in . return count(../HiringManagerName[. << $i]) + 1', 'INT')
    FROM
        @xml.nodes('HiringManagers/HiringManagerName') AS n(v)
),
ct_me AS (
    SELECT
        Email=n.v.value('(.)','NVARCHAR(256)'),
        rn_index=n.v.value('for $i in . return count(../HiringManagerName[. << $i])', 'INT')
    FROM
        @xml.nodes('HiringManagers/Email') AS n(v)
)
SELECT
    ct_mn.HiringManagerName,
    ct_me.Email
FROM
    ct_mn 
    INNER JOIN ct_me ON 
        ct_me.rn_index=ct_mn.rn_index;
```

Result:

```
╔═══════════════════╦══════════════════╗
║ HiringManagerName ║      Email       ║
╠═══════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ Lauren            ║ Lauren@hello.com ║
║ Michael           ║ Michael@bye.com  ║
╚═══════════════════╩══════════════════╝
```